# Issue with importing data into csv file for matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to data analysis with matplotlib and I was hoping I could get some guidance as to where I'm going wrong. As part of a personal project, I've made a face mask detection system using a raspberry pi following the tutorial on https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-face-mask-detector . This part works great, however I was hoping to take it a step further by using the data it produces to form a graph of mask adherence over a period of time

In my attempt I created 2 variables, "mask_off" and "mask_on". When a person is detected wearing a mask or not, the corresponding value increases by 1. From here I was hoping to write these variables to a csv file and plot a graph from there using the values. The code I've written below doesn't seem to run at all:

```
from time import sleep, strftime, time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('home/pi/face_mask_detection/mask_adherence.csv', 'a') as log:
    while True:
        nwm = mask_off
        wm = mask_on
        y.append(mask_off)
        x.append(mask_on)
        plt.clf()
        plt.scatter(x, y)
        plt.plot(x,y)
        log.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),str(nwm)))
        log.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),str(wm)))
        plt.pause(1)
        plt.draw()
```

When I run the code I only get "Import Error: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import" so I can't even test if the code actually works. Chances are I'm taking the complete wrong approach to this so any kind of guidance, advice or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to try to reinstall numpy.

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebooks in an environment other than the `(base)`?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks for the response. As far as I know I'm not using Jupyter Notebooks for the data analysis - just writing it directly to a csv file and trying to make a graph from that. Looking at it now though using that could definitely be a better approach to take

Comment: @ScottBoston I completely agree but unfortunately I've gotten nowhere on that end. I've tried uninstalling it, updating it, scaling back to previous versions and renaming scripts within the numpy directory but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: You might consider using [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#linux-installers), which is the conda package management system, through which you can install the specific precompiled packages you need.